# Postage Stamp Problem with 3 stamp types

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> The Baker does not sell individual bear claws, but sells them in boxes
>   of 6, 9, and 20. Assuming an unlimited supply,  what is the largest
>   number of bear claws that I cannot buy from the baker.

I'm not sure how to attack one of these problems when given three types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You can buy $n$ bear claws, where $n \in N =\{6a+9b+20c \,| a,b,c \in \Bbb{N}\} $.

Let $M = \{m|m \in \Bbb N \wedge m \notin N\}$.

You want $\sup M$.

Notice that if $b,c = 0$, every sixth number is in $N$. This implies that if six consecutive numbers are in $N$, all numbers greater than those will also be in $N$.

Answer (score 3):

As you are probably aware, there is a [well-known formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_.3D_2) for the largest value not obtainable from the set $\{a, b\}$ where $a,b$ are coprime, called the Frobenius number, and given by $g(a,b) = ab - a - b$.

In the case of three numbers, it appears that there is [no known general formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_.3D_3), but there are efficient algorithms for finding $g(a, b, c)$.

In a case such as the one you give, I find that the most sensible approach is to start by looking at $g(9,20) = 180 - 20 - 9 = 151$, so that $g(6,9,20) \le 151$. Then you can use the easily verified fact that the numbers obtainable using just $6$ and $9$ are all multiples of $3$ greater than $3$, from which we can say that if it had been exactly all the multiples of three, then your answer would have been $g(3,20) = 37$.

So we know that $37 \le g(6,9,20) \le 151$, and intuition would indicate it is much more likely to be nearer 37 than 151. From here, you can do a few trials and make use of the 6 consecutive number property that has been given by shade4159 to get the true answer without too much work.

Answer (score 0):

With $6$ and $9$, we see that this creates all multiples of $3$ except $3$ itself.

With $3$ and $20$, we see that the largest number not creatable by these is $3*20-3-20=37$.

The largest number not constructable with the three numbers, is $1$ modulo 3, near $40$, since this number would be created from $40$ and some multiple of $3$.  But we can't make $43$, because $3$ can not be made, so $43$ is the largest number not constructable.